# Most efficient way of purging of 10TB data from SAN?

Tags: linux, san

I want to purge storage data from SAN which accumulates to 10 TB. The storage is mounted as mount-points on a system for which it is visible I was recommended by a friend to use winscp But I don't think the tool is efficient to such an extent. I appreciate if I can be recommended a tool or command line which can help me perform this job. Thanks

Comment: Purge as in `rm -rf /*`? Or securely erasing everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login with ssh, unmount the disk, reformat it.

- If you are on Windows use Putty to ssh in NAS.
- Once logged in, you'll have to find the drive with `mount` command.
- Unmount the drive with `unmount` command
- Format the drive with `mkfs`
- Mount it back using `mount` again

`man command_name` would show a command reference

Comment: With what tool or tools would one do this?

Comment: Depends on the filesystem. For everything `ext`, that would be `e2fsprogs`. `reiserfs` tools are provided by `reiserfsprogs`. Generally, these will already be installed. Short version: `umount /dev/sdx1 && mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdx1 && mount /dev/sdx1`